# match the order of an array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there anyway to match two arrays to see if they are identical, including the order they are in.
so `[1,2,3,4]` would match to `[1,2,3,4]` but not `[1,3,2,4]`, [`2,1,4,3]` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a  = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [1,3,2,4];
var c = [1,2,4,3];
var d = [1,2,3,4];

if(a.join('|') === b.join('|')) {
    console.log('Same');    
}
else {
    console.log('Not same');    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4],
    b = [1,3,2,4],
    equals = a.length == b.length;

if (equals) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
      equals = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might also want to check whether the arrays have the same length first, that would rule out obvious cases.

Comment: @Tonio Good point. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic, i hope it will help you

```
 var arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
 var arr2 = [1,2,4,4];
 var verify = true;

 for( var x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++ ){
    if( !(arr1[x] == arr2[x]) ){
       verify = false;
       break;
    }
 }

 if(verify){
   alert("match");
 }
 else{
    alert("not match");
 }
```

Comment: This is actually not true. The OP wants to know whether two arrays are `identical`. Your code verifies that array `arr1` matches the `beginning` of array `arr2`. See @hsz's answer.